# How to return data from function in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, function

I'm trying to return data from a function but didn't get proper data

```
export const getApi = (url) => {
    return fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => {
            console.log(json);
        })
}
```

```
 {"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}
```

this is my response

i'm calling it here

```
 componentDidMount(){
   const data= getApi(banner)       
   console.log('data',data)       
}
```

Comment: I guess you will have to learn about the concept of promises https://javascript.info/promise-basics and javascripts asynchronous natur https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

Unsure precisely what you're trying to accomplish in the grand scheme, but based on the code snippet, you need to do it this way:

```
export const getApi = (url) => {
   return fetch(url)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then(json => json)

}
```

Then use it like so:

```
componentDidMount(){
   getApi(banner).then(data => console.log("data", data))   
}
```

Comment: Thanks , I got it now fixed my problem

Comment: @AlokSingh You're welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer if it addressed your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your function to this. It is also more readable.

```
export const getApi = async (url) => {
   const response = await fetch(url);
   const json = await response.json();
   console.log(json);
   return json;
}
```